# How Can I Have Gzip Data by zlib.dll?

Tags: visual-c++

i want to compress specified size of binary data, to "gzip" format. by zlib api. (zlib.dll)

if i use gzopen() and gzwrite() functions, the compressed data will write in a file(gzFile), but i want data of compressed (gzipped) in a buffer .
please help me

Comment: For compressing data, you use a function deviously called [`compress`](http://www.zlib.net/manual.html#Utility)

Comment: By all means, use compress. But if you need to do work piece-by-piece, check out the [nicely explained zlib usage example](http://www.zlib.net/zlib_how.html). Basically you set up a z_stream with input and output buffers/buffer sizes, call deflateInit, deflate for each time you fill the input buffer, and then deflateEnd.

Comment: yes, i need to compress data piece_by_piece. but, not by deflate() function. i need data in "gzip" format to send a http response.

Comment: what is the difference between this functions :compressed() and deflate() ?